# How to perform update query optimization in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables, say Table1(14,79, 992 records) and Table2(29,45,329 records). I am trying to update the table1 based on data in Table2 using a query similar to the following,

```
UPDATE Table1 SET (col1, col2) =
    (SELECT col1_1, col2_1 FROM Table2
     WHERE Table1.3 = Table2.3_1 and Table1.4 = Table2.4_1
           and Table1.5 = Table2.5_1 and Table1.6 = Table2.6_1
           and Table1.7 = Table2.7_1 and Table1.8 = Table2.8_1
           and Table1.9 = Table2.9_1 and Table2.year = '2026')
```

This is done as there is no single unique identifier between the two tables, and I have to use the combination of multiple columns to perform the update.
However, the query has very poor performance.
Can you please suggest what might be done to improve the query performance (creating index on the columns? creating index on the combination of the columns)?

I am using Postgres

Comment: No `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output, so no way to answer.

Comment: Why you are storing a year as a string?

Answer (score 0):

Typically using a FROM clause is faster than a co-related subquery:

```
UPDATE Table1 
  SET (col1, col2) = (Table2.col1_1, Table2.col2_1)
FROM Table2
WHERE Table1.3 = Table2.3_1 and Table1.4 = Table2.4_1
  and Table1.5 = Table2.5_1 and Table1.6 = Table2.6_1
  and Table1.7 = Table2.7_1 and Table1.8 = Table2.8_1
  and Table1.9 = Table2.9_1 
  and Table2.year = '2026'
```